# jquery-videosub how to

Tags: video, streaming, subtitles

> Standards compliant video subtitles for HTML5 video tags. Original MooTools implementation by Thomas Sturm, jQuery port by Max Wheeler.
>
> Usage
>
> UsageDead simple. Call the videoSub() function on any jQuery collection of video elements. This will probably look something like:"
>   `$('video').videoSub();`

This might be dead simple for some but not for me. Where does this code go?

The subtitles for flv is starting to become something for the too hard basket for me because it really requires some understanding of security in terms of changing and implementing code on the RED5 server side of things.

Now I even question my use of RED5 for streaming pre-recorded video. Surely Red5 is only really useful for streaming LIVE broadcast. Perhaps I should put my pre-recorded video in various formats in a folder outside of RED5 and let the player do the streaming work. In fact I think that is the next thing I shall try.

Comment: What exactly is your question? Do you want to add subtitles to your flash streaming video? Do you want subtitles on a normal video element? Or you want help with videoSub? Or do you want information about how to migrate your videos from the streaming server to a normal web server? It might help to reformulate. Also, you might have more luck with programming questions on [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com).

Comment: unfort I've been banned from stackoverflow forum because they say I ask dumb questions.

Comment: my question is WHERE does that jquery code go?

Comment: Please give use more details, it's absolutely not clear what you want to know and why you are currently doing. If this is simply about web programming, it's offtopic.